# Wrong daily reputation total on profile page

Tags: support, bug, reputation

While answering [a question about daily reputation limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341891/295232) I noticed something odd in my reputation history. My profile shows a [total reputation gained of 204 for December 4th, 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2) (for you all, it'll be 203 because of the private reputation event, as explained in the linked question). But I fail to see how the events should add up to 204, since except for the bottom three, they're all multiples of 10.

[image]

The [reputation audit tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/reputation) has the following output for that day; it's the same except for the undownvote (which is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207973/295232)). It shows a total of 200, exactly what you would expect, since there are no accepts/bounties on that day.

```
 2    339571 (10)
 2    339582 (10)
 2    339235 (10)
 3    xxxxxx (-1)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 3    339635 (-2)
 2    339635 (10)
 3    339635 (-2)
 2    339635 (10)
 3    339635 (-2)
 2    313755 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    339328 (10)
 3    339635 (-2)
 3    339635 (-2)
 2    321555 (10)
 2    321555 (10)
 2    334415 (10)
 2    339635 (10)
 2    335646 (10)
 2    336908 [1]
-- 2019-12-04 rep +200  = 103293
```

Comment: Is there anything odd when you expand the different posts?

Comment: Nope, I see the same as you do there.

Comment: Did you make any undownvotes that day?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I don't know, but I think they'd show up as well. It might be that an answer I downvoted (before Dec 4) was deleted, but that happens regularly and I can't find another instance where the total is wrong in the recent past.